# При нажатии на объект создается слишком много объектов вместо одного. Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Такая ситуация. По нажатию на объект шестиугольника должен создаваться другой шестиугольник. Однако помимо него создается еще туча других. Только начал работать в Юнити и хотелось бы, чтобы люди знающие поделились опытом со мной, неопытным.
Вот код скрипта:

```
public class mouseclick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;
    public GameObject obj2;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out RaycastHit hit, 100) & Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                GameObject go = hit.collider.gameObject;
                if(go != null)
                {
                    Destroy(go);
                    Instantiate(obj, new Vector3( go.transform.position.x, 0, go.transform.position.z), Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0));
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, 100) & Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            {
                GameObject go = hit.collider.gameObject;
                if (go != null)
                {
                    Instantiate(obj2, new Vector3(go.transform.position.x, 0, go.transform.position.z), Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0));
                    Destroy(go);
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

На рисунке ниже видно, как я добавил этот шестиугольник "Тайл3поле" и сколько его ненужных копий создалось скриптом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я не помню, но может Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) отрабатывает несколько раз при нажатии, хотя вроде не должна, но посмотрите вдруг оно, напишите print("клик") после проверки нажатия  и посмотрите не отрабатывает ли это много раз

Comment: @MadokaMagica , написал Debug.log - отработало много раз

Comment: Вангую. Объектов создается столь-ко же, сколько объектов на которых висит компонент `mouseclick`, а висит он на каждом хексагоне.